# Updating specific data in MySql table through form

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I am making a online application used for storing user data and order information. I have successfully managed to create a system to which you first add customers and then add orders to specific customers.

I now want to create a function that would let the administrator of the page edit a certain line in the table.

I managed to figure out how to manually change it through a MySql code but I cannot figure out how to change it through a form? Right now I have this, but I do not think this is the correct way to do it... It works, but is very limited. For example, I am not sure what to do, if admin selects date?

PHP AND HTML

```
<?php
$id = $_GET['id'];

?>
<form action="update.php" method="POST" >
    <input type="text" name="id" style="display:none;" value="<?php echo $id; ?> placeholder="Hidden id">
     </select>       
    <select name="change"style="width:32.9%;"  required>
      <option selected hidden value="">Select a entry you want to edit</option>
      <option value="narocnik">Customer</option>
      <option value="naslov">Adress</option>
      <option value="kraj">City</option>
      <option value="enaslov">E-mail</option>
      <option value="telefon">Number</option>
      <option value="datumzacetka">Start date</option>
      <option value="datumkonca">due date</option>
      <option value="material">Material</option>
     </select>
 <input type="text" name="new" style="width:32.5%;" placeholder="New entry">

     <input type="submit" value="Pošlji">
  </form>
```

AND THE MYSQL PART

```
<?php
include 'baza.php';
$change   = $_POST['change'];
$new   = $_POST['new'];
$id = $_GET['id'];
$id = $_POST['id'];

$sql = "UPDATE projekti SET $change='$new' where id='$id'";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
 header("Location: projekti.php?id=$id");
} else {
    echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

As I said, the function works, but it is far from perfect, so any suggestions would be very welcome :) The most important thing would be the ability to have all the fields displayed but only update the newly inputted ones.

Comment: Your script is wide open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's

Comment: What does _"It works, but is very limited"_ mean? Limited how?

Comment: Replace `<input type="text" name="id" style="display:none;" value="<?php echo $id; ?> placeholder="Hidden id">` with the simpler, hidden input type `<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>>`

Comment: Hey, thanks, i  am a beginner so i did not know that :( Will check out your suggestion ;)

Comment: @MagnusEriksson As you can see, you can only edit one field, you cannot change dates...

Comment: You should also remove `$id = $_GET['id'];` since it doesn't make sense and should throw an "undefined index"-warning.

Comment: Well if you want to change other fields, just add them to the FORM

Comment: I think some tutorials about HTML forms and handling forms with PHP would be a good starting point for you.

Comment: And [here is the manual page that can get you started](http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php) and here is [a tutorial ](https://www.the-art-of-web.com/php/form-handler/)

Comment: It does not since it is used to edit a specific order (i have multiple for one user) :) @MagnusEriksson

I understand that adding additional fields would be the best. So i just add then all and then check if the field is full and add it in?

Comment: I'm not sure who you're answering and what comment? Use `@username` in your comment to tag specific people (like you've done in other comments).

Comment: Just do some tests and read the links @RiggsFolly posted a few comments up and I'm sure you will get the hang of it.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I guess that is the best way to learn :)